# how to replace a special character from a column of file

Tags: shell, unix

I have a file which contains 6 columns, each field separated by pipe the second last column contains amount field.

```
 140121059|01/01/201400:00:45|[1390]|[387]|17.64|10    
 140121060|01/01/201400:00:46|[1112]|[867]|26.46|10    
 140121062|01/01/201400:00:47|[182]|[13]|4,117.60|10    
 140121065|01/01/201400:00:48|[1088]|[385]|1,147.04|10
```

I want to remove commA from the amount column as I'm not able to put some operations on this column. , is not coming in all columns. And I'm using bash.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `awk`:

```
awk -F '|' -v OFS='|' '{ gsub(/,/, "", $5) } 1' file
```

Output:

```
 140121059|01/01/201400:00:45|[1390]|[387]|17.64|10    
 140121060|01/01/201400:00:46|[1112]|[867]|26.46|10    
 140121062|01/01/201400:00:47|[182]|[13]|4117.60|10    
 140121065|01/01/201400:00:48|[1088]|[385]|1147.04|10
```

- `-F '|' -v OFS='|'` sets both input field separator and output field separator to pipe `|`. This basically sets column separator as `|`.
- `gsub(/,/, "", $5)` removes all commas in 5th column.
- `1` commands the actual printing.
- Same output would follow if input is not indented with extra spaces.

Using `bash`:

```
while IFS='|' read -ra LINE; do LINE[4]=${LINE[4]//,}; IFS='|' eval 'echo "${LINE[*]}"'; done < file
```